# How do I fix warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a script that runs that needs to use notify-send, but runs as root. The only thing I found that works is  [this script](https://github.com/makubi/bash-helper-scripts/blob/master/libnotify/notify-send-as-root.sh) . The problem is that on this line:

```
DBUS_SESSION=`grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$DBUS_PID/environ | sed -e s/DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=//`
```

I keep getting the error

```
warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
```

How do I fix or suppress the error message?

 By the way the following don't suppress it:

```
2> /dev/null
> /dev/null
>> /dev/null
> /dev/null 2>&1
2>&1
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This warning appears to be a new feature in Bash-4.4 - see for example [Command substitution with null bytes generates warning](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2016-09/msg00015.html).

One option would be to strip off or convert the null byte in your pipeline e.g.

```
DBUS_SESSION=$(grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$DBUS_PID/environ | tr '\0' '\n' | sed -e s/DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=//)
```

(note that I switched to the modern `$(. . .)` form of command substitution, in place of backticks).

Alternatively, you could use the bash shell's builtin `read` command, which can deal with null delimiters directly e.g.

```
IFS== read -d '' _ DBUS_SESSION < <(grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$DBUS_PID/environ)
```

(split the null-delimited grep output into two tokens separated by the `=` character; assign the first to junk variable `_` and the second to `DBUS_SESSION`).

*[I couldn't really test these as I don't have a suitably recent version of bash]*

Comment: Is `tr -d '\0'` also ok?